# UITableVIew inside UIScrollView does not reload

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` with a `UITableVIew` on bottom. This `UITableView` grows up and down dynamically, so i don't know the size until I press a "`update button`".

When I press the "update button" I update the `UITableView` `frame` and the `UIScrollView` `height`.
The weird thing is that the `UITableView` is not visible until I press 2 times the update Button...

Does anyone see the error? I tried everything, like `setNeedsDisplay` or calling `[self viewDidLoad]` but it didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
    -(IBAction)update:(id)sender {
[[ApiHandler instance] update:self.item.hash complete:^(NSInteger responseCode,  NSInteger status, NSArray *comments, NSDictionary *reason) {
    if(responseCode == 200) {
        [self.item setStatus:status];
        [self.item setComments:comments];

        [self initViews];  
    } 
}];
```

}

```
- (void)initViews {

if(self.item.comments.count > 0) {
    [self.commentsTableView setHidden:NO];
}else {
    [self.commentsTableView setHidden:YES];
}

NSInteger numOfRows = self.item.comments.count;
long tableHeight = numOfRows * 110;

int height = (650 + tableHeight);
[self.constraint setConstant:height];  //Height constraint for the UIView inside the UIScrollView.

CGRect tableFrame = [self.commentsTableView frame];
tableFrame.size.height = tableHeight;
[self.commentsTableView setFrame:tableFrame];
[self.commentsTableView reloadData];
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I just added a Constraint to the UITableView height like that:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *commentsTableHeightConstraint;
```

And then I update the constraint:

```
- (void)initViews {

if(self.item.comments.count > 0) {
    [self.commentsTableView setHidden:NO];
}else {
    [self.commentsTableView setHidden:YES];
}

NSInteger numOfRows = self.item.comments.count;
long tableHeight = numOfRows * 110;

int height = (650 + tableHeight);
[self.constraint setConstant:height];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    self.commentsTableHeightConstraint.constant = tableHeight;
    [self.commentsTableView reloadData];
    [self.view needsUpdateConstraints];
}];
```

}